# Sample mean lognormal variables

Tags: probability, mean, lognormal-distribution, estimators

Suppose you've got $x_1, ..., x_n$ independant realisation drawn from a $LogNormal(\mu, \sigma^2)$.
Could someone explain me why $exp(\mu + 0.5*\sigma^2)$ $\neq$ $\frac{1}{n}(x_1 + ... + x_n)$ ?

Here are a few lines of python code that show the difference :

```
mu = 3
sigma = 2
lognormal_values = np.random.lognormal(mean=mu, sigma=sigma, size=10000)
sample_lognormal_mean = sum(lognormal_values) / 10000.0
theoretical_lognormal_mean = np.exp(mu + 0.5*(sigma**2))
print(sample_lognormal_mean, theoretical_lognormal_mean)

## -- End pasted text --
(157.50576341554637, 148.4131591025766)
```

Comment: The left hand side (the theoretical mean) is a constant while the right hand side (the sample mean) is a [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable)

Comment: what happens if you increase the sample size?

Comment: Damn, I though a sample of 10 000 would be enough, but indeed, with a bigger sample, it gives the same thing. So it's just about the lognormal distribution taking high values I presume

Comment: The law of large numbers demonstrates the sample mean will approach the arithmetic mean of the underlying distribution, which indeed equals $\exp(\mu+\sigma^2/2)$ under the usual parameterization.

Comment: If you look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_estimation_of_parameters) under MLE, you'll see that a possibly better estimate of parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ which might enable you to get a better estimate of the lognormal theoretical (population) mean. You can't expect even the best estimate to be exactly correct.

Comment: Check the standard deviation/standard error, then you will find that your result is reasonable and acceptable.